# symfony2 ajax call always return null data

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.7 and I query the information from the database and show it on the page however i want to get the current values via api connection through Ajax call by clicking the button but I always get the null response from Ajax Controller.

```
<div>
    <p id="product">1K0615301M1</p>
    <p id="product">1K0615301M2</p>   
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Check"/>
</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#submit').click(function(event) {
             var productNr = [];
             $('#product').each(function() {
                 productNr.push($(this).html());
             });
             console.log(ProductNr); // value of ProductNr
             var ajaxRequest;
             event.preventDefault();

             ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                 url: " {{ path('frontend_api_product') }}",
                 type: "post",
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                 data: ProductNr,
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
 </script>
```

My Controller:

```
public function AjaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $sparepart = $request->request->get('data');

    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'sucess'=> true,
            'data' => $sparepart
        ));
    }
    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Console.log

```
 Object { sucess: true, data: null }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data object has no `data` key, you cannot retrieve it by doing `$request->request->get('data');`

To get the whole object, use `$data = $request->request->all();`

There is many errors in your code.
You are pushing values in `productNr` instead of `ProductNr`.
You have many elements with the same id (An id is uniq, you have to use classes).

**EDIT**

The problem is coming the format of the data your are sending.
To send an object like `{"data":["1K0615301M1","1K0615301M2"]}` , use:

```
var ProductNr = { data: [] };
var ajaxRequest;

$('.product').each(function() {
    var product = $(this).text();
    ProductNr.data.push(product);
});
ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(ProductNr),
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Use `JSON.stringify` to serialise data before send it.
See [How do I POST an array of objects with $.ajax (jQuery or Zepto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109795/how-do-i-post-an-array-of-objects-with-ajax-jquery-or-zepto)

Comment: I do have Request Param in the code... But I still get **null** response from the controller for both `$data = $request->request->all()` and `json_decode($request->getContent(),true`

Comment: Try to remove the contentType

Comment: also how can i add 'data' key so that its easier to get the value in the Controller

Comment: I have also tried with `ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                     url: " {{ path('frontend_api_product') }}",
                     type: "post",
                     processData: false,
                     data:'asdf',
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(data);
                     }

                 });` and I still get **Null** response

Comment: See changes in my answer, the code is working well now.

Comment: I have copied the exact same thing as above([code](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/a9ca07b7fe5ca3af54f7)) and i still have "null" data. [image](http://tinypic.com/r/29vltw/9)

Comment: I just copy/paste the code of your gist and it works well. See [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/a0wust) . Try to clean your cache by doing `rm -rf app/cache/*` . If it doesn't work, say me your symfony version

Comment: I have cleared cache many times that was the first thing i did. It is still null [ScreenShot](http://tinypic.com/r/9swhhx/9) I am using Symfony version 2.7.8

Comment: The problem is surely coming from you (jQuery version, server configuration, or just mistakes). It can come from a lot of reasons and I cannot help you beyond making the code functional (for me).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Just one last question how can set the data object to `data`?  Simply  `ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                     url: "{{ path('frontend_api_product') }}",
                     type: "POST",
                     data: {'data' : ProductNr,
                     processData: false,
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(data);
                     } `

then simply in controller do `$data = $request->request->get('data');` right?

Comment: I've created a repository that you can test and use to debug and find where is the problem in your code. https://github.com/chalasr/stackoverflow-trying

Comment: I've updated my answer for you have a `data` object. I've also push the changes to the repository, you can use it and try.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, if you find what was causing the problem in your project, please keep me informed here

Answer (score 0):

Change
  `data: ProductNr,`
to

```
data:{data:ProductNr}
```