# Ajax is not passing data to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my ajax call. Before ajax call I am tracking some data from html and pushing all these data to an array. After that I am passing that array to controller through ajax call, but its not working  .

**ajax call:**

```
 $("#moveAllRowsContractprijsGrid").click(function () {
        var model = [];
        $("#storingBody tr").each(function () {

            var myModel = {
                Scontractid: $(this).find('td').eq(0).find('input').data('id'),
                IssueTypeId: $(this).find('td').eq(1).find('input').data('id'),
                StoringsItemId: $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('input').data('id'),
                StoringsItem: $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim(),
                IssueType: $(this).find('td').eq(4).text().trim()
            }
            model.push(myModel);

        });
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("AddAllStoringItemsInContractprijs", "Storingsitems")',
            data: model,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            failure: function (response) {
            }
        });
    });
```

**controller:**

```
 public IActionResult AddAllStoringItemsInContractprijs(List<StoringsitemsViewMode> model)
    {
        //model.Incontract = true;
        //var returnModel = model;
        //_storingsitemsService.AddAllStoringItemsInContractprijs(model);
        //return Json(returnModel);
        return null;
    }
```

**data transfer objects:**

```
    public class StoringsitemsViewMode
    {
    public int Scontractid { get; set; }
    public int IssueTypeId { get; set; }
    public string IssueType { get; set; }
    public bool? Analyse { get; set; }
    public int StoringsItemId { get; set; }
    public string StoringsItem { get; set; }
    public bool Incontract { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of data: model try sending data using data: JSON.stringify(model)

Comment: no its not working count 0 in controller.

Comment: Have look to the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109795/how-do-i-post-an-array-of-objects-with-ajax-jquery-or-zepto

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(model), its also not working