# Ajax POST and Stringify Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am learning about POST with Ajax and I've noticed a lot of examples using stringify on static arrays.

In my example I am building array via jQuery objects extracted from `<input>` values.

### Jquery

```
    function PostEdit(vData){
        var content = JSON.stringify(vData); //content = "[{"Id":"1","Date":"7/12/2017 12:00:00 AM"}]"

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "PostViewData")',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ ViewData : vData }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success" + result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("failure" + result);
                }
        });
        return;
    }
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<DataViewModel> ViewData )
    {
        if(ViewData != null)
        {
            var json = new { success = true };
            return Json(json);
        }
        return Json(false);
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public DataViewModel(string id, string date)
    {
        Id = id;
        Date = date;
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Where `DataViewModel` is a class that consists of two values, `Id`, and `Date` which correspond to my JS object.

Since `vData` enters the function as value `vData = [Object]`, When I call `.stringify(vData)` it returns `content = "[{"Id":"1","Date":"7/12/2017 12:00:00 AM"}]"`

The value of `content` above is how I see most examples structured before stringify such as the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109795/how-do-i-post-an-array-of-objects-with-ajax-jquery-or-zepto).

Once in this format, this is when most responses, examples call stringify anyway.

Now when I call `.stringify(ViewData : vData)` I dont even make it to the controller. Ajax fails to post. On the contrary when I call `.stringify(ViewData : content)`, I make it to the controller, but with a null value. What am I missing / misunderstanding?

I'm looking for a better explanation of Ajax Post and Stringify, and how it interacts with the controller parameter.

Comment: did you try "data: vData"?

Comment: Pass like this `var myArray = new Array(); myArray = {"Id":"1","Date":"7/12/2017 12:00:00 AM"}; var myData = { ViewData : myArray };` Then in your ajax **data:myData,** That's it!

Comment: What is `DataViewModel`?

Comment: @Musa `DataViewModel` is a class that consists of two values, `Id`, and `Date` which correspond to my JS object.

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi yes

Comment: Is `Date` in your code behind a `Date` date or a `String` date?

Comment: @BasantaMatia this did not work, plus content is already in array form is it not?

Comment: @Musa I've added the model to my question. It started as a `Date` object originally, then I changed to string when I had issues.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your API. Try this "public ActionResult Index([FromBody]List<DataViewModel> ViewData )" with "data: vData". Because if you send a JSON List via Ajax, so you API properly waiting for that should recognize the List.

Comment: Is it get request or post?

Comment: @Steve it says `[HttpPost]`

Comment: None of that solved your problem?

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes, I will post a full answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add parameterless constructor to your model. With that change, your code will work as it is. ASP is unable to parse your json as DataViewModel since it's trying to call default constructor that doesn't exists.

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public DataViewModel()
    {

    }
    //...other methods and members here
}
```

Comment: This was the working solution. Is there any way I could have found this out through debugging?

Comment: You won't see the exception thrown in VS as it happens before your code inside the action method runs. What I always do is checking Network tab in the browser inspector tool. Instead of a json response it returned default error page. Talking in general, I had came across this error message in a range of situations. Whenever you have a constructor that takes arguments, you are forced to create a parameterless constructor if it's going to be called. However if the class has no constructor whatsoever then you still can create instances without passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution below.
There's another way of doing this

```
    function PostEdit(vId, vDate){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/PostViewData/Index' // it should be '/controller/method'
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: vId, Date: vDate}),  
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success" + result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("failure" + result);
            }
    });
    return;
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Id, string Date )
{
    if(Id != null)
    {
        var json = new { success = true };
        return Json(json);
    }
    return Json(false);
}
```

Update: In the controller method, it should be string id, string date
Update: The constructor should be parameterless. From the answer mentioned below

```
public DataViewModel()
{

}
```

Comment: I had the stringify mostly as an example to show that data was actually there, I can stringify anywhere. I'd prefer to do inside of ajax generally. I just wanted to show the data was in `vData` to begin with.