# Show popup message on ajax edit

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to know how can I show popup message after user changed field and updated data by AJAX?

here is my code:

```
public function UpdateorderbuyerByAjax(Request $request) 
{
    try {
        $id = $request->input('pk');
        $field = $request->input('name');
        $value = $request->input('value');

        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
        $order->{$field} = $value;
        $order->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
    }

    return response('', 200);
}
```

PS: Using `Laravel 5`.

## update

my full java script code, i need to show custom message to user only when he/she changed `// buyer update` part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // buyer update
    $('.user').editable({
        source: [
            @foreach($users as $user)
                { value: '{{ $user->id }}', text: '{{ $user->name }}' }
                @unless ($loop->last)
                    ,
                @endunless
            @endforeach
        ]
    });

    // update status
    $(function() {
      $('.status').editable({
          source: [
              @foreach($orderstatuses as $status)
                  { value: '{{ $status->id }}', text: '{{ $status->title }}' }
                  @unless ($loop->last)
                      ,
                  @endunless
              @endforeach
          ]
      });
    });


    // transaction code
    product_id = $(this).data('pk');
    url = $(this).data('url');

    $('.transaction').editable({
      url: url,
      pk: product_id,
      type:"text",
      validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) === '')
        {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

## UPDATE 2

my latest code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (response) {
          alert(
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam eius odio eum soluta atque voluptatibus ducimus, debitis corrupti! Enim pariatur voluptates, dolor doloremque dignissimos cum amet veritatis deleniti voluptatibus sunt!'
            );
        }
    });

    // buyer update
    $('.user').editable({
        source: [
            @foreach($users as $user)
                { value: '{{ $user->id }}', text: '{{ $user->name }}' }
                @unless ($loop->last)
                    ,
                @endunless
            @endforeach
        ]
    });

    // update status
    $(function() {
      $('.status').editable({
          source: [
              @foreach($orderstatuses as $status)
                  { value: '{{ $status->id }}', text: '{{ $status->title }}' }
                  @unless ($loop->last)
                      ,
                  @endunless
              @endforeach
          ]
      });
    });


    // transaction code
    product_id = $(this).data('pk');
    url = $(this).data('url');

    $('.transaction').editable({
      url: url,
      pk: product_id,
      type:"text",
      validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) === '')
        {
          return 'This field is required';
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show your javascript code.

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar updated my question

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar updated my question.

Comment: show your full ajax javascript code. It's still not enough.

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar done.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs you have to catch the response from your server. The way you do it realy depends on the way you make your ajax-call on the frontend (using jQuery, VueJS, Axios etc).
Using jQuery something like this should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { pk: 456, name: "John", value: "Boston" },
    statusCode: {
      400: function() {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Status updated!" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

More about [Jquery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

If you use Laravel with Axios (which is preinstalled in Laravel 5.5), your ajax-call could look something like this:

```
axios.post('/your-url', {
    pk: 456,
    name: 'John',
    value: 'Boston'
}).then(function (response) {
    alert("Status updated!");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

More about [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

## Update

This is the code you should use:

```
// buyer update
$('.user').editable({
    source: [
        @foreach($users as $user)
            { value: '{{ $user->id }}', text: '{{ $user->name }}' }
            @unless ($loop->last)
                ,
            @endunless
        @endforeach
    ]
});

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/your-target-url",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(source),
    statusCode: {
      400: function() {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Status updated!" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Headers are now set directly in the ajax-call. JSON.stringify is neccessary to transform your data-array into an json-string ([more to read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109795/how-do-i-post-an-array-of-objects-with-ajax-jquery-or-zepto)).

Now you can wrap your code in some event-fired-function (on click or something else).

Comment: I added my Ajax code to my question, would be appreciate if you can tell me about that.

Comment: it will stop my info to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

jQuery had success and error method on AJAX. You can read more about it on [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The following is to work on your code.

When users click the `update_button` you send ajax request to `your_target_url` with `data` and when ajax request is successful, you show the alert.

```
$('update_button').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: your_target_url,
    data: 'data',
    success: function (response) {
      // show your alter on here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: as i said i need it for `buyer update` part which is `$('.user').editable({` you gave me code on wrong method which is `transaction`

Comment: ok this one works but the problem with it is it shows alert for all changes. i need it have effect only for `$('user').editable({`, I will update my code to see what i did.