# Django: get data from array of objects sent by ajax formdata

Tags: json, ajax, django, form-data, django-request

I would like to access `option_rows` data that is sent from the front end of the web application. I use an array to store a collection of objects, include text and image, and append it into formdata, send via ajax. The console log of `option_rows` is as the image below.

However, I couldn't access each data in the array. How could I access each element of `option_rows`? Please also point out what is wrong with the code below as well. Thank for answering.

**Javascript code:**

```
var option_rows = [];
option_rows.push([{option_name : option_name,
                    answer : answer,
                    option_img : option_img}]);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('option_rows', option_rows);
$.ajax({
  url: "{% url 'add_question' %}",
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(){
    $("#addModal").html("");
  },
})
```

**option_rows log:**
[image: option_rows data]

---

**views.py:**

```
def add_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        option_rows = request.POST.get('option_rows')
        print option_rows
        print type(option_rows)
```

**output:**

[image: Python code output]

Comment: I suggest to use JSON.stringify()
formData.append('option_rows', JSON.stringify(option_rows));
Then load json in add_question - json.loads(request.body)

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan using JSON.stringify() and json.loads() work for string and other data type. But for `File type`, after json.loads(), it is emptied. -In this case, the array `option_rows` includes `option_name`, `answer`, `option_img`. How to do overcome this?

Comment: @Sokunthaneth You're trying to send JS objects over HTTP. It won't work. You need to convert them to string. But since you're trying to send multiple objects, I guess you're stuck. Instead of sending data in an array, if you send the elements one by one, that may work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I POST an array of objects with $.ajax (jQuery or Zepto)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109795/how-do-i-post-an-array-of-objects-with-ajax-jquery-or-zepto)